# CDC channel stops receiving messages and never picks back up

Tags: streaming-api, .net, change-data-capture

Working on integrating Salesforce changes back to SQL server, so we have a cometD connection in our .NET app for listening to changes to a specific entity in salesforce, then we can parse out the fields we want and update them. This works great for a few minutes at a time but eventually it stops receiving those messages.

There was a case in which the connection stops after ~2 hours, which was easily solved because we can react to the 403 message that's received when the connection breaks and simply resubscribe. This has run the past 4 days in a development environment and like clockwork we can see the "meta/connection" and "meta/handshake" "meta/subscribe" logs for all of that time but no change updates since ~20-30 minutes after the initial deploy.

Is there anything where it'll stop sending them for some reason that we might be missing? Or anything else that comes to mind?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.